# How to clean up a a failed constructor

Tags: c++, raii

Let's say I am writing a class which wraps up a C style API.

```
int cstyleInit()
int cstyleCleanup()
```

In general, the approach would be to put `cstyleInit()` in my constructor and `cstyleCleanup()` in the destructor, but my question is, how do I handle the the initialisation failing in the constructor?

The simple approach would be something like:

```
MyWrapper::MyWrapper()  {
    int ret = cstyleInit()
    if (ret = FAILUREMODE1) {
        cstyleCleanup();
        throw exception("failure mode 1");
    }
    else if (ret = FAILUREMODE2) {
        cstyleCleanup();
        throw exception("failure mode 2");
    }
    ...
}
```

As far as I can tell that would work fine.  The only (minor) issue is that you have to call cstyleCleanup() explicitly for each failure mode, which doesn't seem very RAII to me.

I know this is a minor issue, but is there a more c++/RAII way of doing this?

Comment: ordinarily you only call a cleanup function for each successful call of init function. are you sure that it also should be called for failed init?

Comment: This is cleanup in the sense of shutting the system down.  I only want to clean up after I am finished with the API or something fails and I'm forced to finish.

Comment: This is really bad design if cstyleInit() require an extra call to cleanup upon failure; I would expect if cstyleInit() fails it should have no side effect and there is nothing required to be do.

Comment: Things that must happen before program exit should come in `main()` in a `catch(...)` block or just after that.

Answer (score 5):

> The only (minor) issue is that you have to call cstyleCleanup() explicitly for each failure mode, which doesn't seem very RAII to me.

It doesn't really relate to RAII, but may be about avoiding to duplicate code when wrapping the API to throw exeptions for specific error codes.
Isn't there something like `ret != NOFAILURE` available for this API,  that enables you to call `cstyleCleanup();` independently of all theses specializations?

```
MyWrapper::MyWrapper() {
   int ret = cstyleInit()
   if (ret != NOFAILURE) {
       cstyleCleanup();
   }
   // Your exception mapping code ...
}
```

Comment: alternatively known as `SUCCESS`.

Comment: @Adam Yes, or `OK`, `0`, whatever the actually wrapped c API specifies for return values to indicate _SUCCESS_ ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the cleanup really should be called also on init function failure, you can do it like this:

```
namespace detail {
    struct Wrapper_base
    {
        int ret_;
        ~Wrapper_base() { cstyleCleanup(); }
        Wrapper_base(): ret_( cstyleInit() ) {}
    };
}  // namespace detail

struct Wrapper
    : private detail::Wrapper_base
{
    Wrapper()
    { if( ret_ != success ) { throw runtime_error( "Blah" ); } }
};
```

There are possible hacks to optimize away the member variable but better keep such things simple.

You can use a `std::map` or whatever you find suitable to customize the exception message. C++11 `system_error` (if I recall the name correctly) has some support for that, but it's very Unix-land specific. So I'd just use a DIY solution, if appropriate.

---

Addendum – one way to remove the `ret_` member variable.

Using C++ constructor delegation:

```
namespace detail {
    struct Wrapper_base
    {
        ~Wrapper_base() { cstyleCleanup(); }
        Wrapper_base( int& ret ) { ret = cstyleInit(); }
    };
}  // namespace detail

class Wrapper
    : private detail::Wrapper_base
{
private:
    Wrapper( int ret )
        : Wrapper_base( ret )
    { if( ret != success ) { throw runtime_error( "Blah" ); } }

public:
    Wrapper(): Wrapper( 0 ) {}
};
```

Comment: What's `success` actually in your sample?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't know, the OP doesn't say. But usually for C APIs it's 0. E.g. in Windows ERROR_SUCCESS and NOERROR and S_TRUE or whatever it was called [checked, it's `S_OK`] are all 0. And so also with Posix error codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RAII. That means you do not have initialization and cleanup functions;  initialization is done by a constructor and cleanup by a destructor. This may mean you need some "helper" objects such as Alf suggests (which should either have copy semantics disabled and move semantics enabled; or use refcounting such as std::shared_ptr).

If you intend to exit your program then throw something that will be caught at the end of `main()` and have your exiting code there.  Then "stack unwinding" occurs and all objects that were previously constructed will be destructed first.

It's hard to be more specific without knowing more about the "C style API" in question. As others point out, an API's cleanup function should only be required if the init function succeeded. You shouldn't mix cleanup of this particular API along with exit-program behaviour.